# How can I change Finder's default sort to filename?

Tags: macos, finder, sort

Since I updated to Lion, every time I bring up a new Finder window the default sort order is by modification date. I want the default sort by filename. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Have you tried removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`? New windows should just be sorted by the same attribute as previous windows.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Open the finder window and hit cmd+j.

Select the settings you want and then at the bottom hit Use As Defaults.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, that doesn't do it. It seems that many folders (Downloads, Documents, etc) have by time as an override. But thanks.

Comment: This is one thing I don't like about OSX, by setting it as default it looks like it only effects the current folder. The folder in which you set it will from now on open in that way, but the others are untouched. You could potentially copy the .DS_Store file from that folder to all other folders. DS_Store is what saves the display information.

Comment: This kind of thing drives me bonkers.  I wish Apple gave you more options to use the OS the way YOU want to, not the way they want you to.  Their way is almost always more cumbersome and exhausting.

Comment: does the job for a specific folder. Is it possible to apply it to all finder folders somehow?

Comment: works in macos Catalina! :)

Comment: What an odd design choice by Apple. Yes, I want the default layout to be a bunch of icons sitting on top of each other with no organization whatsoever. That's just right for me...